# Recompilation not working with groovlets

Tags: groovy

I'm new to groovy, really like it, but found a compilation problem. I'm using Jetty as a webserver, which is serving *.groovy* files (groovlets).

Consider two files:

*Test1.groovy* which contains

```
println new Test2().property
```

*Test2.groovy* which contains:

```
public class Test2 {
   String property = "print this"
}
```

When calling */Test1.groovy* in a browser it prints *print this*. But when I change the property in something else, it still prints *print this*, it won't recompile. The only thing I can do is restart jetty.
Note that when all the code is in one file, recompilation does work.

Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason it's always displaying the default value is because you're `new`ing it inline ... or is that just a problem with the example?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but that's not it.
I am getting a little closer, the compiler can be fooled:
When calling */test2.groovy* in a browser you get a server error, because test2.groovy only contains class code (and not a main method), but when you add the line
   `println ""`
 to this file, it actually recompiles when calling it in a browser.
After that, *test1.groovy* should be recompiled too in order to make it work. It's not a very neat solution, but jetty doesn't need to be restarted this way...